# Google data studio pie chart add custom legend text or label

Tags: looker-studio

Hey I am really new to google data studio and for this project I successfully added pie chart with contains gender details. As I am using CUSTOMER table which adds gender_id while they fill out the form. Customer tables looks like

```
Name   Email             DOB          gender_id
David  david@gmail.com   08/08/1990     1
Shyam  shyam87@gmail.com 09/01/1985     2
Krita  krita96@gmail.com 01/01/2000     3
Suja   Suja@gmail.com    02/03/1995     2
```

I used the customer table to count total gender and pie chart displays legend or label as 1,2,3 and 4. Is there a way to change 1, 2, 3 and 4 into male, female, non-binary and dont want to say.

Pie chart looks as

[image: Pie chart Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you will have to add a new field to your database. The new field must convert the numbers to the respective texts, using the formula:

```
CASE 
   WHEN  gender_id=1 THEN "male"
   WHEN  gender_id=2 THEN "female"
   WHEN  gender_id=3 THEN "non-binary"
   WHEN  gender_id=4 THEN "dont want to say"
END
```

Thus, you will have a new column explaining each genre. Instead of using the column with the numbers, use the new field created as dimension of the pie chart.